# Collect several events before posting using Subject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

i need to collect several event, not every time, before I will send the request.

```
const subject = new Subject();
subject.subscribe((event) => post(event));
const keydown$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
keydown$.subscribe(d => subject.next(d);
```

Comment: Please clarify by which logic you want to aggregate events. By time? By number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`bufferTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferTime):

```
keydown$.bufferTime(2500).subscribe(…);
```

[image: bufferTime]

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you need to unsubscribe from `keydown$` after the `subject` is triggered. Than you need to use `takeUntil` operator:

```
keydown$.takeUntil(subject).subscribe(d => subject.next(d);
```

If you can aggregate events by time you can use smth like

```
const DELAY_TIME = /** some delay time */ 2000;
const subject = new Subject();
subject.subscribe((event) => post(event));
const keydown$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown');
keydown$
  .scan( (acc, cur) => [ ...acc, cur ], [] )
  .delay(DELAY_TIME)
  .last()
  .subscribe( eventsArray => subject.next(eventsArray) )
```

Comment: No, I need to send here not one event, for example, array of events
    subject.subscribe((event) => post(event));

Comment: When do you need to stop collecting events? Please, explain more detailed what is the problem

Comment: I don’t need to stop it. I want to collect events during page is active. But not to send request every time event triggers, I want to send more then one event at the moment.

Comment: Than you can use 'scan' operator to collect events to array like '.scan((acc, cur) => acc.push(cur), [] )'. But you have to use BehaviorSubject

Comment: Cool, thank you, and how to send it by time interval?

Comment: `keydown$
  .scan( (acc, cur) => [ ...acc, cur ], [] )
  .delay(DELAY_TIME)
  .last()
  .subscribe( eventsArray => ... )`

Comment: There's a built-in operator to solve this, see my answer.